# Get all data from cassandra

Tags: python, cassandra

Im trying to fetch all the data from my cassandra database with a python GET method, but cannot seem to get all the values.

I've tried several solutions without any result. When I call the method I only get the first row from that cassandra table, I want everything in that table.

This is the code so far:

Any ideas?

```
@api.route('/getAllApps')
class getAllApps(Resource):
    @api.marshal_list_with(model)
    def get(self):
        return ar.getAllApplications()
```

```
 def getAllApplications(*args):
        for data in AddApplication.objects().limit(None):
             return data
```

Comment: you have return statement in for loop... hence only first record..

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how much data is in your cluster across how many nodes, but queries like "fetch all the data from my cassandra database" usually do not end well for anyone.